# Insert into select to remote database using DB_link

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

I am trying to update the remote database table using DB_LINKS, where I get error

```
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Case Scenario -

1. **From local database** - connect as sysdba

   ```
   sqlplus / as sysdba
   ```
2. **Update remote database with values fetched from local database**

   ```
   INSERT INTO username.D_BackupStatus@db_link_name
   (SELECT    ''''
       || (SELECT DECODE (db_unique_name, NULL, name, db_unique_name)
             FROM v$database)
       || ''','''
       || TO_CHAR (START_TIME, 'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss')
       || ''','''
       || TO_CHAR (END_TIME, 'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss')
       || ''','''
       || time_taken_display
       || ''','''
       || TRIM (STATUS)
       || ''','''
       || INPUT_TYPE
       || ''','''
       || DECODE (TO_CHAR (start_time, 'd'),
                  1, 'Sunday',
                  2, 'Monday',
                  3, 'Tuesday',
                  4, 'Wednesday',
                  5, 'Thursday',
                  6, 'Friday',
                  7, 'Saturday')
       || ''','''
       || (SELECT host_name FROM v$instance)
       || ''''
   FROM V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
   WHERE     TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (START_TIME, 'dd-mon-rr'), 'dd-mon-rr') >=
           TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE - 6, 'dd-mon-rr'), 'dd-mon-rr')
       AND input_type IN
              ('DB FULL', 'DB INCR')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
              order      by   START_TIME);
   ```

**Output**

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
insert into username.D_BackupStatus@db_link_name 
(select '''' ||
(select decode(db_unique_name,NULL,name,db_unique_name) from v$database)||''','''||
to_char(START_TIME,'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss') || ''','''||to_char(END_TIME,'dd-mon-rr hh24:mi:ss') 
|| ''',''' || time_taken_display|| ''',''' ||trim(STATUS) || ''',''' || INPUT_TYPE||''','''
||decode(to_char(start_time, 'd'), 1, 'Sunday', 2, 'Monday',3, 'Tuesday', 4, 'Wednesday',5, 'Thursday', 6,
'Friday',7, 'Saturday')||''','''||(select host_name from v$instance) ||''''
from V$RMAN_BACKUP_JOB_DETAILS
where to_date(to_char(START_TIME,'dd-mon-rr'),'dd-mon-rr')>=to_date(to_char(sysdate-6,'dd-mon-rr'),'dd-mon-rr')
and input_type in ('DB FULL','DB INCR')
order by START_TIME)

Error at Command Line : 11 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Can anyone help me with the query, what is wrong??

Comment: Does the SELECT part work on its own?

Comment: By the way, the `'d'` format mask of `to_char()` is notoriously dependent on NLS_TERRITORY, so for example your decode expression gives Monday here (Western Europe), Tuesday in North America and Wednesday in much of the Middle East (see [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6d9016899346e74e5d6cd2f1488b3587)). In any case, there's already a format mask for that: `to_char(start_time, 'fmDay', 'nls_language=English')`

Comment: Also, `to_date(to_char(start_time, 'DD-MON-RR'), 'DD-MON-RR')` is a timebomb - try it with a date in 2050. Instead, use `trunc(start_time)`.

Comment: Why are you trying to concatonate all of the selected columns into a single string? Doesn't the target table have matching columns?  Why, in your WHERE clause, are you converting DATE types (sysdate and - presumably - start_time) into character strings, just to convert them back to DATE?  And why are you re-creating the Y2k issue with your use of the 'RR' date mask?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, the select part is working fine on its own. This project is a global project and we have a standard time format on all servers which is CET time zone only. So this excludes getting different values from the decode expression. Also now, I am using **trunc(start_time)**.

Comment: @EdStevens I am concatenating all columns so that column values are wrapped by single quotes and I can supplement this output in **Insert into table_name@db_link values (--here single quote wrapped values like 'a','b','c')**.   Now, I have written pl/SQL cursor code to perform the same action.

Comment: Why, in your WHERE clause, are you converting DATE types (sysdate and - presumably - start_time) into character strings, just to convert them back to DATE? And why are you re-creating the Y2k issue with your use of the 'RR' date mask?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ORDER BY` clause from a subquery; it is *invalid* in that context.

```
       AND input_type IN ('DB FULL', 'DB INCR')
       -- ORDER BY start_time
                                               );
```

Can't tell what will happen next, apart from the fact that you could have used the q-quoting mechanism and avoid that many single quotes.

Comment: After removing the **order by** clause. I am getting a new error.  

Error report -  
SQL Error: ORA-00947: not enough values<br/>
00947. 00000 -  "not enough values"<br/>
*Cause:    <br/>
*Action:<br/>

Comment: It's not a subquery though, just a regular INSERT-SELECT with brackets around the SELECT for some reason.

Comment: "Not enough values", @Ravi, means that you should specify all column names (in INSERT) which then must match all column names returned by SELECT.

Comment: After reading all the above suggestions, I made some changes and start hitting the oracle bug/error - **ORA-2070 during a remote Insert over Database link while selecting from local dictionary view (Doc ID 744219.1)**  FInally wrote PL/Sql cursor code as mentioned in the doc id and now it is working as required.